# Input missing focus on each change

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple number input. When I change the value it looses focus. So if I write 13 I first have to add 1 then select the input again and click 3. I tried to minimize the problem to this sandbox:

Thanks to xadm I now have a sample that reproduces the problem here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bind-input-kzzd3

Comment: Do you have more code to paste?

Comment: `GetSearchForm` redefined on each `Insight` render - move definition outside of `Insight` ... `useRef` is for focus - read docs

Comment: What do you mean by this? "move definition outside of Insight"

Comment: just code order - functional components code (all !) is run on every change - `GetSearchForm` definition shouldn't be there

Comment: Got it I can no reproduce the problem https://codesandbox.io/s/bind-input-kzzd3. I am brand new to REACT so sorry for stupid questions. Just want to make sure I understand. I should move GetSearch out in the root of the file so the component is not a function inside the Insights component. If it is inside it will be rendered every time something is change in the insights component?

Comment: new definition = new function ref - different ref - rerendering new compont 'instance' .... don't create bad examples - fix your problem by good order of code or define it in external file !!!

Comment: Yes I will test. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Is this correct approach? https://codesandbox.io/s/bind-input-kzzd3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/bind-input-5stm7. It works correctly.

Every time your main component re-renders it returns a new copy of GetSearchForm. Hence a re-render which results in field losing focus.